# Removing strings from txt file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file output from a sc query(`sc "\\%inputHostName%" %operationMode% "%serviceName%" | findstr /i "SERVICE_NAME STATE" >> temp.txt`) that will generate an output like this

```
SERVICE_NAME: Adobeservice 
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING 
SERVICE_NAME: AppHostSvc 
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
```

I then split the file using the delimiter as ":" and print the output as an HTML table. But by doing so it creates multiple entries of SERVICE_NAME and STATE in rows which I don't want. I only want the values of these variables. Any way to either pick only the value of these variables from the sc query or when the output is generated, get rid of the variable names and create a new temp txt file like this

```
Adobeservice : RUNNING
AppHostSvc : RUNNING
```

Comment: Your provided command line makes no sense, because you have used the default 'State' option for `sc.exe`, which is 'Active'. That therefore excludes all paused or stopped services and will therefore very likely only produce results which are `RUNNING`. For that reason you probably only need to isolate the service names, and append `: RUNNING` directly to each. The following should do all of those 'Active' services at once: ```@For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\SC.exe "\\%inputHostName%" Query ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "SERVICE_NAME"') Do @Echo %%H : Running```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables to track the content of each line, and substring modification in conjunction with an If condition to identify each line type. doing so requires delayed expansion to be enabled and variables to be expanded using `!expansion!`:

```bat
@echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"

Set "Lastline="
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("temp.txt")Do (
 Set "Line=%%G"
 If defined Lastline (
  For /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%j in ("!Line!")Do Echo(!LastLine:* =!: %%j
  Set "LastLine="
 ) Else If "!Line:STATE=!"=="!Line!" Set "LastLine=!Line!"
)
```

Comment: The above code snippet doesn't seem to be closed properly, running the code with QUERY option to find status gives the output, but if I redirect the output to a temporary txt file, the code breaks stating that temporary file doesnot exist.

Comment: @Amit The code above works as expected - If you have modified the above code and are having issues with the modified code not working as expected, you should post the modified code in a question and detail what is happening vs what you expect to happen.

Comment: @T3RROR, I have posted another querstion with the code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236137/batch-script-throwing-error-for-missing-txt-file-with-sc-command. Please have a look, much appreciated for all your help.

Comment: @Amit with regards to your issue with the redirection of the output, the entire code block from the outermost for loop should be wrapped in parenthesis. `>"temporary.txt" (code block)`