# Batch Script throwing error for missing txt file with sc command

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch script which is used to START/STOP/QUERY `service` status of windows services on remote servers. Assuming the batch script name is service_check.bat, the script is called as `service_check.bat settings.txt QUERY/START/STOP`, *(obviously just one of either of those three)*. This script generates a table report after the process is complete. The issue is that it works fine when we call the service with QUERY option, but fails with START or STOP. The settings file reads as `192.168.1.200 "AxInstSV"`. Please suggest where I am going wrong with this.

```
'''
REM @Echo OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

:: Clear the screen
CLS

:: Assign input to variables
SET settingsFile=%~1
SET inputOperationMode=%~2

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') 
do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "hr=%dt:~8,2%"
set "mn=%dt:~10,2%"
set "today_date_time=%YY%_%MM%_%DD%_%hr%_%mn%"
echo %today_date_time%

SET /A ERR_INPUT_FILE=1
SET /A ERR_INVALID_PARA=2   

:: Log File
SET Logbase=%~dp0Log
SET logFilePath="%Logbase%\AutoServiceLog_%inputOperationMode%.txt"


:: Log file check, generate if not present
if not exist %Logbase% (
    mkdir %Logbase%
    ECHO [%date% %time%] [INFO] Log file created successfully >> %logFilePath%
)

:: Settings File Check
if [%1] == [] (
    ECHO Invalid Settings File 
    ECHO [%date% %time%] [INFO] Invalid Settings File >> %logFilePath%
    EXIT /B ERR_INPUT_FILE
)

:: Check input operation mode not empty
if [%2] == [] goto :EmptyCommand

:: Check correct input operation mode
::if /i [%2] NEQ ["START"] if /i [%2] NEQ ["STOP"] if /i ["%2"] NEQ ["QUERY"] goto EmptyCommand

REM if not exist %settingsFile%
REM (
    REM ECHO Settings File does not exist in the desired location 
    REM ECHO [%date% %time%] [INFO] settingsFile Settings File does not exist in the desired location  >> %logFilePath%
    REM EXIT /B 2
REM )

ECHO --------------------------------------------------- >> %logFilePath%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (%settingsFile%) do (
call:ServiceOperation %%a %%b %inputOperationMode%
REM pause
)
call:RemoveTags temp.txt
call:CreateHTMLTable temporary.txt %Logbase%\SERVICEINFO_%inputOperationMode%_%today_date_time%.html
if exist temp.txt del /f /q temp.txt
if exist temporary.txt del /f /q temporary.txt
ECHO --------------------------------------------------- >> %logFilePath%
goto:eof

:: Service Operation Function
:ServiceOperation 
SET inputHostName=%~1
SET serviceName=%~2
SET operationMode=%~3

ECHO [%date %time] 
sc "\\%inputHostName%" %operationMode% "%serviceName%" >> %logFilePath%
sc "\\%inputHostName%" %operationMode% "%serviceName%" | findstr /i "SERVICE_NAME STATE" >> temp.txt
REM pause
goto:eof

:: EmptyCommand Function
:EmptyCommand
ECHO INVALID INPUT
ECHO [%date %time] [ERROR] INVALID INPUT >> %logFilePath%
EXIT /B ERR_INVALID_PARA

:CreateHTMLTable <inputfile> <outputfile>
setlocal
>%2 echo ^<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
>>%2 echo "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
>>%2 echo  "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"^>
>>%2 echo ^<HTML^>
>>%2 echo ^<HEAD^>
>>%2 echo ^<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" 
>>%2 echo CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"^> 
>>%2 echo ^</HEAD^>
>>%2 echo ^<BODY^>
>>%2 echo ^<h1^> FRDMP SERVICE RUNNING REPORT ^</h1^>
>>%2 echo This report was generated on :: [%date% %time%]
>>%2 echo ^<style type="text/css"^>
>>%2 echo .tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 2px;border-color: #bcaf91;border-collapse: collapse;}
>>%2 echo .tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#ded0b0;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91;text-align:left;}
>>%2 echo .tftable tr {background-color:#e9dbbb;}
>>%2 echo .tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91;}
>>%2 echo .tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
>>%2 echo ^</style^>
>>%2 echo ^<table class="tftable" border="1"^>
>>%2 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>SERVICE_NAME_DESC^</td^>^<td^>STATE^</td^>^</tr^>
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (%1) do (
>>%2 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%a^</td^>^<td^>%%b^</td^>^</tr^>
)
>>%2 echo ^</table^>
>>%2 echo ^</BODY^>
>>%2 echo ^</HTML^>


:RemoveTags <inputfile> <outputfile>
@echo off
Set "Lastline="
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("temp.txt")Do (
 Set "Line=%%G"
 If defined Lastline (
  For /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%j in ("!Line!")Do Echo(!LastLine:* =!: %%j
  Set "LastLine="
 ) Else If "!Line:STATE=!"=="!Line!" Set "LastLine=!Line!"
) >> temporary.txt
:: ========================================================================
::              FUNCTION BODY END
:: ========================================================================
```

'''

Comment: The `AxInstSV` service runs as LocalSystem under svchost.exe. It does not accept `stop` and it does not accept `pause`. Essentially the service provides User Account Control validation for the installation of ActiveX controls from the Internet and enables management of ActiveX control installation based on Group Policy settings. The only way to bypass it would be to configure the service as disabled, then reboot the machine, install your malicious payload, then reconfigure the service as manual, then reboot again!

Comment: The AxInstSV service was just an example, it can be any service, mostly it will be our application service name. I just picked this up from services.msc. The issue is even with admin privileges, it throws same error that the temporary.txt file doesn't exist. Any help is appreciated. I will take the other suggestions into account and work upon them.

Comment: If a service is being run as LocalService @AmitGope, then the user Administrator, another user within the Administrators Group, or running the script/command elevated does not necessarily give you the required permissions to control it. In addition, as you've decided to use a service which is bespoke, or secret, only you know what those permissions are, or what kind of interaction your service accepts. What is the output from `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Service Where Name="AxInstSV" Get AcceptStop, Started, StartName, State /Format:CSV`, obviously after replacing `AxInstSV` as needed.

Comment: It also appears in your provided code that if `%1` has no value, you are writing a message to `\Log\AutoServiceLog_.txt`. As you can see, if there is no `%1`, then there is also no `%2`, which means that `%inputOperationMode%` is undefined, and as that is used in the value of `%logFilePath%` that file would not be named as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the code where both sc query was using the same inputOperationMode. Added conditional check and it works fine for all operation modes of START/STOP/QUERY. Piece  of changed code looks like this:

```
if "%operationMode%" NEQ "QUERY" echo %operationMode%
(
sc "\\%inputHostName%" %operationMode% "%serviceName%" >> %logFilePath%
)
sc "\\%inputHostName%" QUERY "%serviceName%" | findstr /i "SERVICE_NAME STATE" >> temp.txt
```

Thank you all for all the suggestions.